# File Rename Macro exiting While Loop Immediately

Tags: excel, vba

Below is code that is supposed to go into a folder, and then save each file to new folder as the name of the author & a count.

The renaming saves the file as me and not the orginal author? Any advice on how I can save it as the original author and not last author?

Let me know if I need to explain more.

```
 Sub RenameExcelFilesbyAuthor()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim Counter As Integer

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
.Title = "C:\Users\Logan\Documents\Excel Folder"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
 myPath = myPath
 If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

 'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
 myExtension = "*.xlsx*"

 'Target Path with Ending Extention
 myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

 Counter = 1

 'Loop through each Excel file in folder
 Do While myFile <> ""
  'ReadOnly = False
    Set wb = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
     Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        wb.Close
    Else
    Counter = Counter + 1
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
     DoEvents

   'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
     wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Name\Documents\New Folder" & ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author") & Counter

   'Save and Close Workbook
     wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

   'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
     DoEvents
    End If

   'Get next file name
     myFile = Dir

 Loop

 'Message Box when tasks are completed
 MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
 'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Should the extension be ".xlsx"? I doubt there are any files with ".xlxs".

Comment: Lol, thats true, let me change that and give it a try.

Comment: typos are the worst :)

Comment: Ok so I changed that and it seems to work, however, when the macro saves the workbook, it makes me the "Last Author", so I need to save it as the original author but it still puts my name instead of the original author. Any advice? I have edited the OP to reflect changes.

Comment: You can change author using `ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author") = "Whoever"` - I'm not sure you can change `Last modified by` because it's a security thing. People could change files maliciously and override who changed it...

Comment: I am not trying to change the author, but save the workbook as the original authors name. I am fine with the last modified being me, but I want the name of the file to dynamically change to the original author of the file when it is saved, not the last modified author. Is there a way to do that? I thought the builtindocumentproperties differentiated that by Last Author and Author but that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

### ThisWorkbook vs ActiveWorkbook

- You have to use `wb`, the `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook`.
- `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook containing this code.
- You're missing a `backslash` (`\`) after `New Folder`.

**The Changed Line**

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Name\Documents\New Folder\" _
  & wb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author") & " " & Counter & ".xlsx"
```

Use `myExtension = "*.xlsx"` (instead of `"*.xlsx*"`) because you want the files ending with the extension so there will be no characters after it.